# JGoodies: Binding multiple swing components to a single model field

Tags: java, swing, jgoodies

I'm trying to create a "duration" field on a swing gui I'm developing.  To do this, I've got 3 JSpinner components.  Days, Hours and Minutes.

```
JSpinner durationDaySpinner;
JSpinner durationHourSpinner;
JSpinner durationMinuteSpinner;
```

If possible I'd like to "bind" these 3 components back to a single domain field:

```
long durationInMs;
```

i.e.

```
durationInMs = days*24*60*60*1000 + hours*60*60*1000 + minutes*60*1000;
```

Can anyone advise how I'd get this working with JGoodies binding?  I've only ever bound single components to model/domain fields.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to add a separate `ValueModel` for each spinner, bind each `ValueModel` to the appropriate spinner, then add a one `PropertyChangeListener` to all three `ValueModels`. When the value held by any of the three spinner-bound `ValueModels` changes, grab each value, calculate the ms like you've done in the question, and set that on the bean property (or `ValueModel`) you want to set.

Essentially you're adding another mini-model between the domain model you're binding into and the UI model in order to map multiple UI-bound components onto a single domain property.

Also, for readability I'd suggest using the `java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit` rather than lots of multiplications.

Eg,

```
long ms = TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(days) + TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(hours) + TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(minutes);
```